# Detect position?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a simple game with a boat moving between left and right by the keys. The moving is OK, but when I try to detect the left och right end it doesn't work at all. Below is a part of the code. What could be wrong?

```
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBoat);

function moveBoat(event:Event):void {
if(! boat.x >= 700){

 if(moveLeft) {
  boat.x -= 5;
  boat.scaleX = 1;
 }
 if (moveRight) {
  boat.x += 5;
  boat.scaleX = -1;
 }


}
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work, specifically? What happens when you reach a boundary?

Comment: Hi, the boat went out of the game area. But I solved that now by this code:

if (moveLeft && boat.x > 70) {
   boat.x-=5;
   boat.scaleX=1;
  }

But now I have another problem. The boat are going to drop bombs at submarines and I wondering how this will be solved in a simple way. The boat should have five bombs, soo I was thinking to use five boolean variables that are false from the beginning and when dropped they get true and falling to the bottom from the boats x position at that moment. Hmmm, any suggestion how to do this? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've solved your collisions problem, here's an answer for your dropping bombs problem. Doing it by having 5 boolean variables would be a rather unrefined way of doing it; instead simply use an integer to record how many bombs your boat has left to drop, and each time it drops one, reduce this value by 1. Here's some example code:

```
//Create a variable to hold the number of bombs left.
var bombsLeft:int = 5;

//Create an event listener to listen for mouse clicks; upon a click, we'll drop a bomb.
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dropBomb);

//The function dropBomb:
function dropBomb(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (bombsLeft > 0)
    {
       //Create a new instance of the Bomb class; this could be an object in your Library (if you're using the Flash IDE), which has a graphic inside it of a bomb.
       var newBomb:Bomb = new Bomb();
       //Position the bomb.
       newBomb.x = boat.x;
       newBomb.y = boat.y;
       //Add it to the stage
       addChild(newBomb);
       //Reduce the number of bombs you have left.
       bombsLeft--;
    }
    //At this point you could check if bombsLeft is equal to zero, and maybe increase it again to some other value.
}
```

This doesn't include code to then move the bomb downwards, but you can do that fairly simply using an update loop. If you're struggling to do that, let me know and I'll give you another example.

Hope that helps.

debu